# Approach to filtering and validating return values with rxjs

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

So here is the scenario I am attempting to figure out how to implement using rxjs:

1. Load some set of metadata from a file/database/etc. Each element in the metadata has an id and additional information - like the location of the actual data. Currently, I am loading all of this metadata at the start of the application, asynchronously. After this data is loaded the Observable calls complete. Eventually I may add a refresh capability
2. At some later point in the application, I will need to load specific sets of data based upon what is available in the metadata. I am currently attempting to do this with a function like **fetchData(ids:string[]):Observable**. This is where I am unclear about how to proceed under the rxjs paradigm. I am equally unsure of what to do with requesting a single item using a function like **fetchDatum(id:string):Observable**

I can of course use filter to operate only on those IMetdata items emitted from the IMetadata Observable that match one of the names in the list - but I also need to confirm that ALL requested items are found in the IMetadata Observable emissions, and if not I need to error.

So if someone requests the IMetadata with id = "Bob" - but there is no such IMetadata emitted from the source Observable, then it needs to error. Or if they request { "Shirley", "Rex", "Samantha" } and there is no data for "Rex" then it should error.

I've considered using a Rx.Subject here, but from what I've read that is generally undesirable under the rxjs paradigm. Please advise on what approaches would work for this scenario under the rxjs paradigm. Thanks!

Comment: You're fighting Rx because you don't really want a stream, you want an object, ```metadata = {}``` (or better yet, ```Immutable.Map()```). The only sense in which your metadata is time-varying is that you update it. You could use an Rx subject holding the metadata (as a single object, not its constituent records). Any parts of your program that depend on the contents of ```metadata``` could subscribe and every time it changes they would get an opportunity to update accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I came up with. This function creates an Observable that relies upon a IBufferEvaluator to tell it what to do with each item that is emitted by the source Observable. It can APPEND the item to the buffer, SKIP the emitted item, CLEAR the buffer, FLUSH the buffer to the subscriber, etc. Let me know if you find a better way to do this, especially if its an out-of-the-box rxjs solution. Thanks.

```
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';

export enum BufferAction {    
    APPEND, /** Append the current emission to the buffer and continue  **/
    SKIP, /** Do nothing, ignoring the current emission if applicable  **/
    FLUSH, /** This will ignore the current emission, if applicable, and flush the existing buffer contents */
    CLEAR, /** Clear the buffer contents. Ignore the current emission, if applicable */
    COMPLETE, /** Mark the Observable as Complete. The buffer will be cleared upon completion. **/
    APPEND_THEN_FLUSH,   /** Append the current emission to the buffer prior to flushing it  **/
    APPEND_THEN_COMPLETE, /** Append the current emission to the buffer and then complete **/
    CLEAR_THEN_APPEND, /** Clear the buffer contents and then append the current emission to it */
    FLUSH_THEN_APPEND, /** Flush the buffer contents and then append the current emission to it */
    FLUSH_THEN_COMPLETE, /** Flush the buffer contents and then mark the Observable as complete */
    APPEND_FLUSH_COMPLETE /** Append the current emission, flush the buffer, and then complete  */
}

export function bufferActionToString(action: BufferAction):string
{
    switch(action)
    {
        case BufferAction.APPEND: return "APPEND";
        case BufferAction.SKIP: return "SKIP";
        case BufferAction.FLUSH: return "FLUSH";
        case BufferAction.CLEAR: return "CLEAR";
        case BufferAction.COMPLETE: return "COMPLETE";
        case BufferAction.APPEND_THEN_FLUSH: return "APPEND_THEN_FLUSH";
        case BufferAction.APPEND_THEN_COMPLETE: return "APPEND_THEN_COMPLETE";
        case BufferAction.CLEAR_THEN_APPEND: return "CLEAR_THEN_APPEND";
        case BufferAction.FLUSH_THEN_APPEND: return "FLUSH_THEN_APPEND";
        case BufferAction.FLUSH_THEN_COMPLETE: return "FLUSH_THEN_COMPLETE";
        case BufferAction.APPEND_FLUSH_COMPLETE: return "APPEND_FLUSH_COMPLETE";
        default: return "Unrecognized Buffer Action [" + action + "]";
    }
}

export interface IBufferEvaluator<T>
{
    evalOnNext(next:T, buffer: T[]):BufferAction;
    evalOnComplete(buffer: T[]):BufferAction;
}

/** bufferWithEval.ts
 *  An Operator that buffers the emissions from the source Observable. As each emission is recieved,
 *  it and the buffered emissions are evaluated to determine what BufferAction to APPEND. You can APPEND
 *  the current emission value to the end of the buffered emissions, you can FLUSH the buffered emissions
 *  before or after appending the current emission value, you can SKIP the current emission value and then
 *  (optionally) FLUSH the buffer, and you can CLEAR the buffer before or after appending the current emission.
 *   
 *  The evalOnNext and evalOnComplete are expected to return a BufferAction to indicate
 *  which action to take. If no evalOnNext is supplied, it will default to APPENDing each emission. The evalOnComplete
 *  will default to FLUSH_THEN_COMPLETE. If evalOnNext or evalOnComplete throw an exception, the Observable will emit 
 *  the exception and cease.
 */
export function bufferWithEval<T>
    (   source: Rx.Observable<T>, 
        evaluatorFactory?: () => IBufferEvaluator<T>
    ) : Rx.Observable<T[]> 
{   
    /** if no evaluatorFactory supplied, use the default evaluatorFactory **/
    if(!evaluatorFactory)
    {
        evaluatorFactory = () => {
            return {
                evalOnNext : function(next: T, buffer: T[]) { return BufferAction.APPEND; },
                evalOnComplete : function(buffer: T[]) { return BufferAction.FLUSH; }
            };
        }
    }

    return new Rx.Observable<T[]>((subscriber: Rx.Subscriber<T[]>) => 
    {
        var _buffer = new Array<T>();          
        var _evaluator = evaluatorFactory();
        var _subscription: Rx.Subscription = null;

        function append(next: T)
        {
            _buffer.push(next);
        }

        function flush()
        {
            try
            {
                subscriber.next(_buffer);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Ignore any exceptions that come from subscriber.next()
                clear();
            }          
        }

        function clear()
        {
            _buffer = new Array<T>();
        }

        function next(next: T)
        {
            try
            {
                var action = _evaluator.evalOnNext(next, _buffer.slice(0));                
                switch(action)
                {
                    case BufferAction.APPEND: { append(next); break; }
                    case BufferAction.SKIP: { break; }
                    case BufferAction.FLUSH: { flush(); break; }
                    case BufferAction.CLEAR: { clear(); break; }
                    case BufferAction.COMPLETE: { complete(); break; }
                    case BufferAction.APPEND_THEN_FLUSH: { append(next); flush(); break; }
                    case BufferAction.APPEND_THEN_COMPLETE: { append(next); complete(); break; }
                    case BufferAction.APPEND_FLUSH_COMPLETE: { append(next); flush(); complete(); break; }
                    case BufferAction.CLEAR_THEN_APPEND: { clear(); append(next); break; }
                    case BufferAction.FLUSH_THEN_APPEND: { flush(); append(next); break; }
                    case BufferAction.FLUSH_THEN_COMPLETE: { flush(); complete(); break; }

                    default: throw new Error("next(): Invalid BufferAction '" + bufferActionToString(action) + "'");
                }   
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                error(e);
            }          
        }    

        function complete()
        {
            try
            {            
                var action = _evaluator.evalOnComplete(_buffer.slice(0));
                switch(action)
                {
                    case BufferAction.FLUSH_THEN_COMPLETE:
                    case BufferAction.FLUSH:  { flush(); } 

                    case BufferAction.CLEAR: 
                    case BufferAction.COMPLETE: { break; }                   

                    case BufferAction.APPEND:
                    case BufferAction.APPEND_THEN_FLUSH:
                    case BufferAction.APPEND_THEN_COMPLETE:
                    case BufferAction.APPEND_FLUSH_COMPLETE:
                    case BufferAction.SKIP: 
                    case BufferAction.CLEAR_THEN_APPEND: 
                    case BufferAction.FLUSH_THEN_APPEND: 
                    default: throw new Error("complete(): Invalid BufferAction '" + bufferActionToString(action) + "'");
                }

                clear();
                subscriber.complete();
                _subscription.unsubscribe();        
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                error(e);
            }           
        }        

        function error(err: any)
        {                  
            try
            {
                subscriber.error(err);
            }
            finally
            {   
                _subscription.unsubscribe();
            }
        }          

        _subscription = source.subscribe(next, error, complete);
        return _subscription;
    });
}
```